# message chunks with writable stream

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm using nodejs 0.10 and [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) (websocket lib).

I would like to implement my own `stream.Writable` class to send websocket messages.
My constraints are :

- I must fragment written data into chunks of 10KB and prepend to them a JSON header before sending them to the websocket
- The JSON header of the last chunk must contain "last: true"

For instance, if I call:

```
myStream = new FoobarStream;
myStream.write(<a buffer of 7KB>);
myStream.end(<another buffer of 7KB>);
```

then, I expect my stream to send this data in two messages: the first will have its JSON header followed by 10KB of data and the second will have its JSON header (containing the "last: true" field) followed by 4KB of data.

It means I must temporize the data sending and it means I must find a way to know when I'm writing the last data of the message because of this "last: true" field I must write into the JSON header.

I don't know how to do that with only inheriting the `_write()` method of stream.Writable. It seems that I cannot know in _write() if end() has been called and so I cannot flag my JSON header with "`last: true`".

Does it mean I have to inherit the `end()` method of the stream.Writable?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define own `end` method and handle from there. But that would mean rewrite some code from the original `end` method.

Instead you can keep an internal buffer and process the last piece of chunk in the `prefinish` or `finish` event. Here is a simple example:

```
function FoobarStream(options){
    Writable.call(this, options);


    this.on('prefinish', function(){
        if(this._buffer){
            //process the last chunk
            process.stdout.write('footer: '+ this._buffer+ "\n");
        }
    });
}

FoobarStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, cb){

    if(this._buffer){
        //process other chunks here
        process.stdout.write('header: ' + this._buffer+ "\n");
        this._buffer = chunk;
    }
    else
        this._buffer = chunk;
    cb();
}

myStream = new FoobarStream;
myStream.write('first line');
myStream.write('second line');
myStream.end('last line');

/*
outputs:
header: first line
header: second line
footer: last fine
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delay writing to the sink (underlying WritableStream resource) until `process.nextTick`, which will allow for you to check if the `finish` (there is no `prefinish` in 0.10) event has fired on the stream before writing the result. Here's an example that you can run:

```
var Stream = require('stream');
var Util = require('util');

// Create a readable to test our FoobarStream out

var readable = new Stream.Readable();
var finished = false;

readable._read = function () {

    if (finished) {
        this.push(new Buffer('world'));
        return this.push(null);
    }

    this.push(new Buffer('hello '));
    finished = true;
};

// Create the FoobarStream

var FoobarStream = function (options, sink) {

    Stream.Writable.call(this, options);

    this.sink = sink;
    this.finished = false;

    this.on('finish', function () {
        this.finished = true;
    });
};

Util.inherits(FoobarStream, Stream.Writable);

FoobarStream.prototype.serialize = function (chunk) {

    var header = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({some: 'header', last: this.finished}));
    return Buffer.concat([header, chunk]);
};

FoobarStream.prototype._write = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {

    var self = this;

    process.nextTick(function () {
        self.sink.write(self.serialize(chunk));
    });

    callback();
}

readable.pipe(new FoobarStream(null, process.stdout));
```

Output in console:

```
$ node index.js
{"my":"header","last":false}hello
{"my":"header","last":true}world
```